# Get data from corrupt lz4 tar archive

Tags: ubuntu, tar, corruption, lz4

I have a tar, that somehow got corrupt.

I very much need some certs and config files I backed up using said file.

Problem is, there's a corrupt folder in the archive and tar bails after hitting it.

Is there any way to force it to get past the corrupt data?

File compressed on Debian 10, decompression on Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24063846/how-to-use-tar-with-lz4

Comment: @PersianGulf that's not really helpful

Comment: You should explain that peoblems you have. Problems with the compressed data stream or problem with the resulting decompredded output?

Comment: @schily >there's a corrupt folder in the archive. As in you know archive is corrupt

Comment: Your wording is not related to  problems that may occur from extracting tar archives. So please explain your problem.